# Drawable folders in res folder?

Tags: android, image, drawable

What is the difference between the three drawable folders in the res folder in the project hierarchy? If I have an image to put into a folder, which folder do I put it in?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I am going to take a guess that "the three drawable folders" are `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, and `drawable-hdpi`. In that case, if you stick with all of those folders, you need to put one image in each, sized to match the indicated screen density. This is discussed in the [online documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) as well as this [blog post](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/02/23/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part-3/). You can find a set of sample projects showing use of different drawable resources based on screen density [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/ScreenSizes/).

If you are just starting out in Android development, you can get rid of all three of those directories and create a single `drawable` directory, putting your image in there. Eventually, though, for a quality application, you will want to test your images on different devices/emulators with different screen densities, and possibly have different images for each density to improve the look of your app.

Comment: You don't NEED to put an image in each; the platform will pick the image that best matches the device's density, and it it isn't exact scale it to match.

Also for applications targeting 1.6 or later, it is strongly recommended that you put your bitmaps in a directory that matches its designed density (it makes no sense to have a bitmap without a density specification); of course non-bitmaps like the various XML drawables generally have no such need and should be in the plain directory.

See also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#AlternateResources

Comment: LINT will complain if you put scalable bitmaps in the /drawable folder. It's currently intended for densityless items such as xml-based drawables.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a reference to [multi device options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

As said by @CommonsWare, you don't **need** to put resources in anything but res/ layout/ or drawable/ but if you want your program to have a better experience on multiple devices with different screens / density / languages you may want to consider that you have that option.

Answer (score 1):

Also interesting, though not specific to images, is how android handles resources. It gives them a load order, where more specific means it'll get picked over less specific.

For example, you have three String values in strings.xml in your values folder. You also have one specific string in a folder called values-en. When android opens your app and your locale matches en, it will load two defaults from the values folder and the third, more specific string, from values-en. If your locale is ru, it will just use the default instead because you have no values-ru folder.

The same is true for images. If android can't find images for your specific screen variant, it will use defaults from the drawable folder.

In my opinion it's good practice to have default values/images in your generic folders like values/drawable and specific values/images in specific folders. This way both current and future devices will at least have a way to display your content until you can provide specific versions.