# Where Should I put the PNG file relate to ImageButton in Android?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm very new to Android.

I created a ImageButton. The main.xml includes code segment as following.

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="50px"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:src="@drawable/cat"
android:layout_x="50px"
android:layout_y="52px"
>
```

Where do i have to put the "cat.png" i have. Do i need to rename it to something else?

Comment: Check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533410/drawable-folders-in-res-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the `res/drawable/` folder in your Android project. Keep the name **cat.png**

Comment: there are 3 folders. drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi ? do i need to put it for all 3? or do i need to change the xml code?

Comment: It depends on if you want it to be different resolution for the different screen dpis. Make it a high-resolution image with 240dpi for hdpi, 160dpi for mdpi and 120dpi for ldpi.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply put in any one folder it will work no need to change xml for that.