# Drawable Folders

Tags: java, android, drawable

What is the difference between the 3 drawable folders? I know how drawable works but I don't understand why there are 3 folders. Can an image be accessed if it is in only one folder and can it also be accessed if it is in more than one? I know someone probably has a quick and easy answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533410/drawable-folders-in-res-folder or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263265/drawable-hdpi-drawable-mdpi-drawable-ldpi-android

Comment: I guess this question makes sense to the developers asking and answering it, but I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read [Application Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html) and [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) sections from documentation. In short, different folders are accessed from different kind of devices.

In short:

- Devices with large dpi (~240dpi) use resources from "drawable-hdpi"
  folder.
- Devices with medium dpi (~160dpi) use resources from
  "drawable-mdpi".
- Devices with small dpi (~120 dpi) use resources
  from "drawable-ldpi" folder.

Comment: so i should keep the same image in all 3 of the folders then?

Comment: You should, but you can go with one folder named "drawable" that will be used for all devices. This is strongly not recommended.