# Applying Calendar Image to Image Button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I wanted to Display Calendar Icon as a Button In Android. I have created a Image Button as,

```
ImageButton DtPk = new ImageButton(this);
```

I know that image will set as,

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/calendar");
DtPk.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

But where do i store image in my project? And how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the project was created you should see a folder called "res" and inside it several different drawable folders. Place the image inside of the one called drawable-mdpi. Then simple do the following:

```
DtPk.setImageResource(R.drawable.calendar);
```

Here is another SO post explaining more about drawable folders: [Drawable folders in res folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533410/drawable-folders-in-res-folder)

And read the section called **Bitmap File** in this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html