# Android drawable folders

Tags: android, drawable, directory

I have one background I have made for my app. But I am not sure which folder to put it in, and in which size?

Which size should I save my background in the ldpi, which size for mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi?

I need a specific size in each folder, to fit all screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

You could put in any folder, the eclipse IDE will pick up automatically no matter which folder your place your background. Recommended for ldpi is 36x36, mdpi = 48x48, hdpi = 72x72 and xhdpi = 96x96. Just check the default icon in you res folder. For more info, view [Difference between each resource folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533444/820388)

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental purpose of having folder ldpi, which size for mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi is to put drawable resources like pictures, and icons  in the ldpi, which size for mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi . The ratio of their coresponding size  from low to extra large is ranged as

36:48:72:96

if you are referring to the background of ypur app. Actually you can programmatically set hr backgeound color or fixed in xml . That is applied to all resolutions.