# Image in android not getting added to @drawable/

Tags: android

Hello I am developing an android application in which for a ListView I have to added an image to drawable folder but when I am adding it is giving the error.

This is the folders hierarchy of my project

[image]

This is the image I wanna add arrow.png

[image]

This is the error

[2013-04-03 20:57:37 - FileSharing] res/drawable/arrow.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

I have changes the file name 10 times according to the conventions but still the error is not going

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project, restart Eclipse, refresh the project?

Comment: On the screenshot, the dot look like a comma?

Comment: Ya I have tried all the things

Comment: and I have checked it is not a comma but adot only

Comment: Please tell me all the possible reasons due to which it is happening if I am not adding the image then it is running fine.

Comment: You may find arrow is a reserved drawable name. Try calling it myarrow.png for example.

Comment: Check if there any space in file name.

Comment: @AwadKab it is already shown in image that it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think you must not put the image file in drawable folder.

you must chose these folder for putting images for your application

[image]

If you didn't see these folder create these folder inside `res` .
Then clean and rebuild your project .Hope this would help you

Also Keep an eye one the name of images `must contain only [a-z0-9_.]`

I think the  default choice is `drawable-mdpi` folder

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533444/1450401)

Comment: How does it make difference?

Comment: drawable/ should work fine, too. You would use the specialized folder if providing different images for different densities

Comment: No I wanna keep it there only and according to conventions I am giving correct name and proper conventions

Comment: i think the drawable folder is to keep custom gradient xml files

Comment: @edwin yes i closed my eclipse then restarted then kept the files in the folders you mentioned. +1 for your correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and build again.

Sometimes eclipse behaves wierd.