# How to use drawable folder in android for Images or icons?

Tags: java, android, image, icons, drawable

How can I use drawable folder in Android Project for different images and icons for different devices?
e.g

1. drawable-hdpi ?
2. drawable-ldpi ?
3. drawable-mdpi ?
4. drawable-xhdpi ?
5. drawable-xxhdpi ?

and What size of images should be placed in particular folder?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html this may help you

Comment: Read this..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533410/drawable-folders-in-res-folder and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use drawable folder. The android platform does that for you. You only need to place appropriate images at appropriate folders and the system will use the resources from that folder. You can have a look at [google iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) for details about sizing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your app design looks like and what size of images your are going to put for your app design. In order to get ratio of LDPI,MDPI,HDPI,XHDPI and XXHDPI images, go through [this](https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) link.