# Android Background image fit screen without stretching

Tags: android, background

I have developed an android application. I used android:background property to make an image as background. But when it is displayed on square displays, the image keeps stretching.
How to make Android Background fit the screen without any stretching ?
I have seen many apps with images or videos that are non stretched , but fills the entire screen of the android phone.

My xml code is given below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/Splash" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It depends on your image. How it looks? Because `android:background="@drawable/Splash"` will cover whole screen and fit to screen.

Comment: Actually its a 1536x2048 image with lot of devices image like in the splash screen of adt/androidstudio. I have seen many apps that fits the background with an image , but not stretched. I cannot post images here. because my reputation in below 10

Comment: Have a look at my answer and see if it helps

Answer (score 12):

You can try and use an `ImageView` rather than setting it to the background of the `RelativeLayout`

I have modified your code to look like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/Splash"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Only problem with this solution is that the image might be cut off at parts on some devices. To solve this issue you can create a few images with different aspect ratios for relevant devices and put them into the relevant `drawable-xxxx` folders.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image) thread for other solutions that might suit your requirements better.

Answer (score 1):

you need severalimage for different displays
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Android to support multiple screen you must have to add different images according to screen resolution and screen size.

For more details just visit these links:

1. [Drawable folders in res folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533410/drawable-folders-in-res-folder)
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use a FrameLayout and put ImageView as background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPlaylistItemBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img_dsh" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```